# No remote machine option on VS Community 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, uwp

I've recently downloaded Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.5.2. I previously had VS2015 which had an option to debug on "local machine" and "remote machine". But on my VS Community 2017 [it just shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtGyG.png). Is this a limitation for VS Community, or is there a fix?

Comment: No, it is not a limitation. My guess is that you didn't install all the dependencies. Can you please post a printscreen of the components in VIsual Studio Installer?

Comment: Hi! my installer asked me to update, will post after it does! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what i'm looking for here, but here's for the sdk https://imgur.com/g3XeULc, then for .net https://imgur.com/zj1UHEg, emulator https://imgur.com/FsFkpks, development activities https://imgur.com/I14HlvH, compiler and build tools https://imgur.com/Olgdyou and code tools https://imgur.com/W2bhyxf.

Comment: Check this link, hope it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by doing a **repair through the Visual Studio Installer**. Should really be a rule of thumb that if something isn't right, go through the installer again.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks for your sharing.